# Div Background Image

Tags: html, css

i just wanted to put the bgbottom to the bottom part of my body.What happens the bottom image is until the end of footer and didn't go beyond to the bottom of the body.

```
#bgtop {
    background-image:url(images/bgtop.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#bgbottom { background:url(images/bgbottom.png) repeat-x bottom;}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="bgtop"></div>
<div id="bgbottom"></div>
```

Comment: Indent your code blocks 4 spaces. Try to ask your question more clearly. While I didn't mind taking 10 seconds fixing your formatting, I'm not going to spend 10 minutes trying to understand your question.

Reduce examples to the SIMPLEST POSSIBLE INSTANCE which replicates your problem. Welcome to SO.

Comment: I concur with Erik ~ I'm not really sure what the problem you're having is... can you mock a screenshot of what you want and show a screenshot of what you're fighting? That could be even faster. (But mostly I mirror his comments of fix the formatting and reduce the example to the MINIMUM ~ Albeit I don't do that well myself sometimes ;-) [Oh, also ~ You'll find that answers come pretty rapidly _and_ over time, so be prepared to monitor your questions for responses shortly after posting ... often within 20 minutes of posting ]

Answer (score 1):

While your question isn't clear, I *think* you're looking to fix an image across the bottom of your page. If this is the case, use the CSS property [`background-attachment: fixed`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-attachment.asp)

After re-reading your question a bit more, I think you may be trying to just get your height to be 100% of the page (again, not really sure)? If this is the case, you can set `height: 100%` or you can apply the background image to the `<body>` tag itself:

```
body { background: #[color] url([image]) repeat-x left bottom; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the 100% height for the body tag does not work, then position the bottom div.
Set the bottom div position property to fixed and set bottom to -1px and left to 0px. This will ensure the background image flows out of the bottom of the browser window.
I think this is a solution to your problem.

```
#bgbottom { background:url(images/bgbottom.png) repeat-x; position:fixed; bottom:-1px; left:0px;}
```